# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() why threads wait for completion before going to next line?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

Trying below code.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_it():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as my_executor:
        t1 = my_executor.submit(doing, 3)
        ret_value = t1.result()
        t2 = my_executor.submit(some_func)
        return f"doing return is {ret_value}"


def doing(num):
    print(f"Calculating Square for {num}")
    return num*num


def some_func():
    print("sleep for 6 sec")
    time.sleep(6)
    print("done sleeping 6 secs")


start = time.perf_counter()
print(do_it())
finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f"total time {finish-start}")
```

Getting below output:

```
Calculating Square for 3
sleep for 6 sec
done sleeping 6 secs
doing return is 9
total time 6.0060749100002795
```

But i was expecting (and want):

```
Calculating Square for 3
sleep for 6 sec
doing return is 9
total time <time much much less than 6>
<then after 6 sec>
done sleeping 6 secs
```

I want the return value of t1 Asap and let t2 continue. How can i achieve it. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote here:

```py
    t1 = my_executor.submit(doing, 3)
    ret_value = t1.result()
    t2 = my_executor.submit(some_func)
```

makes the two functions (`doing` and `some_func`) running sequentially instead of concurrently because you explicitly blocked and awaited the value of the first one using `.result()` before launching the second one.

If you want to run the two functions concurrently, then you must submit them before awaiting them:

```py
def do_it():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as my_executor:
        t1 = my_executor.submit(doing, 3)
        t2 = my_executor.submit(some_func)
        ret_value = t1.result()
        return f"doing return is {ret_value}"
```

Here, `t1` and `t2` runs concurrently, they are submitted at (almost) the same time. You then await for the result of `t1` via `.result()` and return its value, this is what you probably want.

However, if you need to await the first available result between the two functions, you can use the `wait` function or the `as_completed` one, take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to learn how to use them.

---

## Edit

The `with` statement opens a context manager that calls the `.shutdown()` of the executor before continuing. This method waits for all futures to complete before returning, hence `do_it()` only returns when t1 and t2 completed.

If you want to return as soon as t2 started, pass the executor as a parameter to avoid calling `.shutdown()` in this function:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_it(executor):
    ret_value = doing(3)
    t2 = executor.submit(some_func)
    return f"doing return is {ret_value}"

def doing(num):
    print(f"Calculating Square for {num}")
    return num*num

def some_func():
    print("sleep for 6 sec")
    time.sleep(6)
    print("done sleeping 6 secs")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    print(do_it(executor))
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"total time {finish-start}")
```

You said that t2 needs the value of t1, so those calls cannot be made concurrent, you can execute t1 serially.

Also, note that it does not really make sense to submit t2 inside the `do_it` function, right after t1 completed. You could submit t2 **after** `do_it` has returned, which is more logical and simpler:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time


def do_it():
    ret_value = doing(3)
    return f"doing return is {ret_value}"

def doing(num):
    print(f"Calculating Square for {num}")
    return num*num

def some_func():
    print("sleep for 6 sec")
    time.sleep(6)
    print("done sleeping 6 secs")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    print(do_it())
    executor.submit(some_func)
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"total time {finish-start}")
```

This does not gives the exact output you want (two print statements are interleaved), but this does not matters anyway, the result is the same, t2 is launched as soon as t1 completed.

Comment: Yes i need the return value of t1 for t2. And t1.result() is blocking t2 execution.
But after t2 execution starts do_it() should return. But it also waiting to t2 to complete.
I want do_it()'s return as soon as t2 starts.

Comment: If you need the value of t1 for t2 then you cannot make their execution concurrent. The `with` statement using the executor automatically calls its `.shutdown()` method at the end, waiting for **all** futures to complete. This causes the return of `do_it()` to wait for t2 too. I updated my answer with a correct answer.